# How to add a library to an existing project on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I add an existing or precompiled library downloaded from the internet, to our project developed in Visual Studio in order to accelerate programming?

Answer (score 1):

`Right Click Your Project -> Add Reference... -> Browse Tab -> Browse... (Button)`

[image]